# Modem, switch & wireless router network connection

Tags: wireless-networking

[image: Network Configuration]

The Network has setup as in image:

1. The modem is a CenturyLink DSL modem with four router outputs. One of the outputs is connected to a Netgear Managed switch.
2. The switch is then connected to four PCs and a printer, forming the network.
3. A wireless router has been connected to the switch but is not linking into the network. Therefore, the laptop cannot access the network.

Do I need to directly link the wireless router to one of the open ports in the modem or do I have to configure the router to a static IP to work directly off the switch. Which would be the best?

Comment: Configure the router to gave a static IP within your existing subnet (but outside your DHCP pool) -> disable DHCP server on wifi router -> plug router into switch using one of the router's LAN ports (NOT its WAN port).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the DSL modem is also doing NAT.  Based on that, you have a couple of options.

A:  See if CenturyLink can configure the DSL modem to be a bridge so you can let your wireless router be the actual NAT router.  You would have to configure your router with the correct WAN information (DHCP, static IP, etc)  It would then go DSL modem (any port) to WAN port of WiFi router to Netgear Switch to endpoints.

B:  If not you can configure your WiFi router to be an AP, disabling any routing, firewall, NAT etc.   Some routers have an actual setting that you can select to enable AP mode.   If it doesn't:
  1. Assign the LAN IP address of the router to a static IP on the same network as the DSL Modem.  (If the DSL modem is 192.168.1.1, assign your router something like 192.168.1.254.)
  2.  Disable DHCP
  3.  Connect a patch cable from your switch to any LAN port of the WiFi router, leaving the WAN port unplugged.

In this case, your laptop would use the router to connect to the network, but use the DSL modem as its DHCP server and gateway.